# PHP : API gethostbynamel not working on windows server 2012

Tags: php, windows-server-2012

I have two windows machines.

- Machine 1: Windows 7 installed and has 2 LAN cards (say IP's are: 1.1.1.1 and 2.2.2.2).
- Machine 2: Windows Server 2012 installed and has 2 LAN card (say IP's are: 3.3.3.3 and 4.4.4.4)

I'm using  PHP API 'gethostbynamel' to get ip address list of server.

In case of **Machine 1**: IP address list getting printed as

```
Array ( [0] => 1.1.1.1 [1] => 2.2.2.2).
```

If i change the LAN priority in windows setting. Then IP order in response array gets changed like:

```
Array ( [0] => 2.2.2.2 [1] => 1.1.1.1)
```

BUT in case of **Machine 2**: IP address list getting printed as

```
Array ( [0] => 3.3.3.3 [1] => 4.4.4.4)
```

And if i change LAN priority in windows setting. Still, order is not changing and printing as

```
Array ( [0] => 3.3.3.3 [1] => 4.4.4.4)
```

When I check LAN priority in command prompt using "netstat -rn" in machine 2, LAN priority is getting changed successfully.

I have no idea, why in windows server 2012 PHP is not changing order of IP addresses on changing LAN priority. **PHP version is 5.5.x.** I hope my question is clear to understand :)